# React component triggering alert before button press along with a POST request before user input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Shows a alert when going to the page and doing a POST request before info is entered into the fields. Could someone possibly tell me or show me what I am doing wrong here. Thanks in Advance! The alert and POST request should only happen after a user fills out the registration form. The Alert to happen when the checks for Email and passwords to match. After that the POST request should happen and get saved to the database through the API.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import uuid from 'react-uuid';

export default function RegistrationForm() {
  const initialForm = {
    first_name: '',
    last_name: '',
    username: '',
    email: '',
    email_match: '',
    password: '',
    password_match: '',
  };
  const history = useHistory();

  const [registrationForm, setRegistrationForm] = useState({ ...initialForm });

  const handleChange = ({ target }, event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setRegistrationForm({ ...registrationForm, [target.name]: target.value });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const currentAPI = `*API*`;
    if (
      registrationForm.email === registrationForm.email_match &&
      registrationForm.password === registrationForm.password_match
    ) {
      alert(`You're Email and Password Matches!`);
      const abortController = new AbortController();
      async function postRegistration() {
        try {
          const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              registration_id: uuid(),
              username: '',
              first_name: '',
              last_name: '',
              email: '',
              password: '',
              password_match: '',
            }),
          };
          //eslint-disable-next-line
          const response = await fetch(currentAPI, requestOptions, {
            signal: abortController.signal,
          });
        } catch (error) {
          if (error.name === 'AbortError') {
            console.log('Post was not successful');
          } else {
            throw error;
          }
        }
      }
      postRegistration();
      return () => {
        abortController.abort();
      };
    } else {
      alert(`Email and Password Do Not Match!`);
    }
  }, []);
  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { first_name, last_name, username, email, password, password_match } =
      registrationForm;
    console.log(
      first_name,
      last_name,
      username,
      email,
      password,
      password_match
    );
    setRegistrationForm({ ...initialForm });
    history.push('/Login');
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ padding: '30px 0px' }}>
      <div className='p-3 rounded' style={{ border: '2px solid #42fcfc' }}>
        <div
          className='card-title'
          style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}
        >
          <h3 className='page-title'>Register</h3>
        </div>
        <form
          onSubmit={submitHandler}
          className='card-body'
          style={{ color: '#fff' }}
        >
          <label htmlFor='first_name' className='d-block'>
            First Name:
          </label>
          <input
            name='first_name'
            type='text'
            id='first_name'
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={registrationForm.first_name}
            style={{ width: '100%', marginBottom: '5px' }}
          />
          <label htmlFor='last_name' className='d-block'>
            Last Name:
          </label>
          <input
            name='last_name'
            type='text'
            id='last_name'
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={registrationForm.last_name}
            style={{ width: '100%', marginBottom: '5px' }}
          />
          <label htmlFor='username' className='d-block'>
            Username:
          </label>
          <input
            name='username'
            type='text'
            id='username'
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={registrationForm.username}
            style={{ width: '100%', marginBottom: '5px' }}
          />
          <label htmlFor='email' className='d-block'>
            Email:
          </label>
          <input
            name='email'
            type='text'
            id='email'
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={registrationForm.email}
            style={{ width: '100%', marginBottom: '5px' }}
          />
          <label htmlFor='email_match' className='d-block'>
            Confirm Email:
          </label>
          <input
            name='email_match'
            type='email'
            id='email_match'
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={registrationForm.email_match}
            style={{ width: '100%' }}
          />
          <label htmlFor='password' className='d-block'>
            Password:{' '}
          </label>
          <input
            name='password'
            type='password'
            id='password'
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={registrationForm.password}
            style={{ width: '100%', marginBottom: '5px' }}
          />
          <label htmlFor='password_match' className='d-block'>
            Confirm password:
          </label>
          <input
            name='password_match'
            type='password'
            id='password_match'
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={registrationForm.password_match}
            style={{ width: '100%' }}
          />
          <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary mt-3'>
            Register
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The `useEffect` function runs immediately when the component is mounted. It seems like you want this to happen after a button click or an action is taken, so an effect seems like the wrong place to have this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the Single Responsibility Principle, we should make each function only do one specific thing, rather than all the things. This makes it easier to debug and understand what exactly each function does.

We don't need the `useEffect` at all since you have two event handlers already -- one for `onChange` (updating form values) and one for `onSubmit` (handling the form submission)

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"
import uuid from "react-uuid"

const initialForm = {
  first_name: "",
  last_name: "",
  username: "",
  email: "",
  email_match: "",
  password: "",
  password_match: "",
}

const RegistrationForm = () => {
  const [registrationForm, setRegistrationForm] = useState({ ...initialForm })

  const history = useHistory()

  // It's only responsibility is handling form input changes
  const handleChange = ({ target }, event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setRegistrationForm({ ...registrationForm, [target.name]: target.value })
  }

  // It's only responsibility is handling the submit
  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const {
      first_name,
      last_name,
      username,
      email,
      password,
      password_match,
    } = registrationForm

    console.log(
      first_name,
      last_name,
      username,
      email,
      password,
      password_match
    )

    validateForm()
  }


  const postRegistration = async () => {
    const abortController = new AbortController()
    try {
      const requestOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          registration_id: uuid(),
          username: "",
          first_name: "",
          last_name: "",
          email: "",
          password: "",
          password_match: "",
        }),
      }
      //eslint-disable-next-line
      const response = await fetch(currentAPI, requestOptions, {
        signal: abortController.signal,
      })

      // not sure what your response looks like, but I would check for a 200
      if (response) {
        // if you need anything from it, you would do additional logic here

        //finally, reset the registration form and navigate
        setRegistrationForm({ ...initialForm })
        history.push("/Login")
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.name === "AbortError") {
        abortController.abort()
        console.log("Post was not successful")
      } else {
        throw error
      }
    }
  }


  const validateForm = () => {
    if (registrationForm.email === "" || registrationForm.password.length < 8) {
      alert(
        `Email must be filled in and password must be 8 characters or more.`
      )
      return
    }

    if (
      registrationForm.email === registrationForm.email_match &&
      registrationForm.password === registrationForm.password_match
    ) {
      alert(`You're Email and Password Matches!`)
      // everything validated, so now we want to post
      postRegistration()
    } else {
      alert(`Email and Password Do Not Match!`)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ padding: "30px 0px" }}>
      <div className="p-3 rounded" style={{ border: "2px solid #42fcfc" }}>
        <div
          className="card-title"
          style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}
        >
          <h3 className="page-title">Register</h3>
        </div>
        <form
          onSubmit={submitHandler}
          className="card-body"
          style={{ color: "#fff" }}
        >
          <label htmlFor="first_name" className="d-block">
            First Name:
          </label>
          <input
            name="first_name"
            type="text"
            id="first_name"
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={registrationForm.first_name}
            style={{ width: "100%", marginBottom: "5px" }}
          />
          <label htmlFor="last_name" className="d-block">
            Last Name:
          </label>
          <input
            name="last_name"
            type="text"
            id="last_name"
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={registrationForm.last_name}
            style={{ width: "100%", marginBottom: "5px" }}
          />
          <label htmlFor="username" className="d-block">
            Username:
          </label>
          <input
            name="username"
            type="text"
            id="username"
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={registrationForm.username}
            style={{ width: "100%", marginBottom: "5px" }}
          />
          <label htmlFor="email" className="d-block">
            Email:
          </label>
          <input
            name="email"
            type="text"
            id="email"
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={registrationForm.email}
            style={{ width: "100%", marginBottom: "5px" }}
          />
          <label htmlFor="email_match" className="d-block">
            Confirm Email:
          </label>
          <input
            name="email_match"
            type="email"
            id="email_match"
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={registrationForm.email_match}
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
          />
          <label htmlFor="password" className="d-block">
            Password:{" "}
          </label>
          <input
            name="password"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={registrationForm.password}
            style={{ width: "100%", marginBottom: "5px" }}
          />
          <label htmlFor="password_match" className="d-block">
            Confirm password:
          </label>
          <input
            name="password_match"
            type="password"
            id="password_match"
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={registrationForm.password_match}
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
          />
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mt-3">
            Register
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default RegistrationForm
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your condition matches when both username and password are empty strings, which includes the initial state.  Perhaps you want something like this to ensure nonempty string:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const currentAPI = `*API*`;
    if (
      registrationForm.email &&
      registrationForm.email === registrationForm.email_match &&
      registrationForm.password &&
      registrationForm.password === registrationForm.password_match
    ) {
      //...
    }
  }, [registrationForm.email, registrationForm.email_match, registrationForm.password, registrationForm.password_match]);
```

Also note that you should specify the dependencies at the end of the `useEffect`, instead of the empty list `[]`.  Alternatively, you can omit the dependency list, but you don't want `[]` in this case.

As mentioned in @Nick's comment above, you might be better off running this code when the Register button gets pressed, avoiding `useEffect` altogether, like so:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import uuid from 'react-uuid';

export default function RegistrationForm() {
  const initialForm = {
    first_name: '',
    last_name: '',
    username: '',
    email: '',
    email_match: '',
    password: '',
    password_match: '',
  };
  const history = useHistory();

  const [registrationForm, setRegistrationForm] = useState({ ...initialForm });

  const handleChange = ({ target }, event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setRegistrationForm({ ...registrationForm, [target.name]: target.value });
  };
  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { first_name, last_name, username, email, password, password_match } =
      registrationForm;
    console.log(
      first_name,
      last_name,
      username,
      email,
      password,
      password_match
    );
    const currentAPI = `*API*`;
    if (
      registrationForm.email &&
      registrationForm.email === registrationForm.email_match &&
      registrationForm.password &&
      registrationForm.password === registrationForm.password_match
    ) {
      alert(`You're Email and Password Matches!`);
      const abortController = new AbortController();
      async function postRegistration() {
        try {
          const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              registration_id: uuid(),
              username: '',
              first_name: '',
              last_name: '',
              email: '',
              password: '',
              password_match: '',
            }),
          };
          //eslint-disable-next-line
          const response = await fetch(currentAPI, requestOptions, {
            signal: abortController.signal,
          });
        } catch (error) {
          if (error.name === 'AbortError') {
            console.log('Post was not successful');
          } else {
            throw error;
          }
        }
      }
      postRegistration();
    } else {
      alert(`Email and Password Do Not Match!`);
    }
  }, []);
    history.push('/Login');
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ padding: '30px 0px' }}>
      <div className='p-3 rounded' style={{ border: '2px solid #42fcfc' }}>
        <div
          className='card-title'
          style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}
        >
          <h3 className='page-title'>Register</h3>
        </div>
        <form
          onSubmit={submitHandler}
          className='card-body'
          style={{ color: '#fff' }}
        >
          <label htmlFor='first_name' className='d-block'>
            First Name:
          </label>
          <input
            name='first_name'
            type='text'
            id='first_name'
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={registrationForm.first_name}
            style={{ width: '100%', marginBottom: '5px' }}
          />
          <label htmlFor='last_name' className='d-block'>
            Last Name:
          </label>
          <input
            name='last_name'
            type='text'
            id='last_name'
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={registrationForm.last_name}
            style={{ width: '100%', marginBottom: '5px' }}
          />
          <label htmlFor='username' className='d-block'>
            Username:
          </label>
          <input
            name='username'
            type='text'
            id='username'
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={registrationForm.username}
            style={{ width: '100%', marginBottom: '5px' }}
          />
          <label htmlFor='email' className='d-block'>
            Email:
          </label>
          <input
            name='email'
            type='text'
            id='email'
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={registrationForm.email}
            style={{ width: '100%', marginBottom: '5px' }}
          />
          <label htmlFor='email_match' className='d-block'>
            Confirm Email:
          </label>
          <input
            name='email_match'
            type='email'
            id='email_match'
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={registrationForm.email_match}
            style={{ width: '100%' }}
          />
          <label htmlFor='password' className='d-block'>
            Password:{' '}
          </label>
          <input
            name='password'
            type='password'
            id='password'
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={registrationForm.password}
            style={{ width: '100%', marginBottom: '5px' }}
          />
          <label htmlFor='password_match' className='d-block'>
            Confirm password:
          </label>
          <input
            name='password_match'
            type='password'
            id='password_match'
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={registrationForm.password_match}
            style={{ width: '100%' }}
          />
          <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary mt-3'>
            Register
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ok so moving the useEffect where? I tried it in the submit handler and didn't work because it's inside a function that's inside the main component. So how can I connect the two?

Comment: I've added a second version of the code to clarify what we meant.

Answer (score 0):

For your useEffect, put the dependecies that change after user click to submit a form if you want only occur at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Function inside the `useEffect()` is called when the application loads the first time. Only use the `useEffect()` when you want to call the function when the page loads the first time. Or When passed dependencies are changed.

I suggest you to move the code inside the `useEffect()` to the `submitHandler()`. That should solve the issue i think